# Transferring files between folders

Tags: bash, ubuntu, synchronization, samba

I need a solution for this script to move files that will drop into the 8953-x folders to a joint folder.
The files that drops to the 8953-x folders will automatically be moved to the joint folder `/mnt/FOLDER`.

It will move all files besides files containing ! in their filename, for example `picture.jpg.!sync`.
Files ending with .!sync are in sync between servers, using btsync and not complete, they shall be ignored. When the sync end, the file output will change to picture.jpg, and then I want it to be transferred to the joint folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

from_folders=(8953-10  8953-11  8953-12  8953-3  8953-4  8953-5  8953-6  8953-7  8953-8  8953-9)
${from_folders[@]}
```

Comment: It sounded at first like you had 8000 folders to move. Are there and folders named `8953-x` that you do not want to move from?

Comment: No, just the `8935-x` in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work, but please test on a backup directory.

```
shopt -s extglob; mv 8953-*/!(\!*) /mnt/FOLDER
```

This turns on pattern matching and then moves all files in those folders which do not start with exclamation to the destination folder.

If the files all are named `.jpg` when ready, it is easier:

```
 mv 8953-*/*.jpg /mnt/FOLDER
```

Comment: When in sync the files are named `file.jpg.!sync`, I need to correct that in the first post. I tried to create a file.jpg.!sync file in a folder, but got the `bash: !sync: event not found`. So I expect that a script is not even needed, because `mv` will not be able to move files containing ! after the dot `.!`.
I'm not sure. The script functioned, `mv` needed root privileges to run it though.

Comment: My answer was for files starting with `!`. It would be simple to change. Do any other files end in `sync`. The `!` is a special character in bash, so you need to put `\!` whenever you use it in the name. Best to avoid it for file names, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

from_folders=(8953-10  8953-11  8953-12  8953-3  8953-4  8953-5  8953-6  8953-7  8953-8  8953-9)
for folder in ${from_folders[@]}
do
echo mv $folder/!(\!*) /mnt/finished_fotograf
done
```